# Trying to return a deep nested object with Lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have not been able to find a solution for this on StackoverlFlow and i have been working on this issue for some time now. Its a bit difficult so please let me know if i should provide more information.

My problem:
I have a JSON object of Lands, each land has an ID and a Blocks array associated with it and that blocks array has block with ID's too.

Preview:

```
var Lands = [{
                'LandId':'123',
                'something1':'qwerty',
                'something2':'qwerty',
                'Blocks': [
                    {
                        'id':'456',
                        'LandId':'123'
                    },
                    {
                        'BlockId':'789',
                        'LandId':'123'
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...More Land Objects];
```

*Note*: The data is not setup the way i would have done it but this was done along time ago and i have to work with what i have for right now.

I am trying to write a lodash function that will take the blockId's that i have and match them and return the landId from the Blocks.

so the end result would be a list of LandId's that where returned from the Blocks.

I was using something like this and it was returning no results:

```
selectedLand = function(Lands, landIDs){
                return _.filter(Lands, function(land){
                    return land === landIDs[index];
                });
            };
```

I know i am going about this the wrong way and would like to know the appropriate way to approach this and solve it. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selectedLand = function(Lands, landIDs){
                return _.filter(Lands, function(land){
                    return land === landIDs[index];
                });
            };
```

Note that `index` lacks any definition in this scope, so this function will essentially never return true, barring a lucky(?) accident with an externally defined `index`. And anytime you call `_.filter(someArr,function(){return false;})` you'll get `[]`. Undefined `index` aside, this does strict comparison of a land object against (maybe) a string in landIDs

I'm a bit unclear on the exact requirements of your selection, so you can tailor this filter to suit your needs. The function **filters** the `lands` array by checking if the `.blocks` array property has **some** values where the `.landID` property is **included** in the `landsID` array.

In closing, if you want to make the most out of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) (or my favorite, [ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/)) I suggest you sit down and read the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs). Sounds deathly boring, but 75% of the battle with data transforms is knowing what's in your toolbox. Note how the English description of the process matches almost exactly with the example code (filter, some, includes).

```js
var Lands = [{
    'LandId': '123',
    'something1': 'qwerty',
    'something2': 'qwerty',
    'Blocks': [{
      'id': '456',
      'LandId': '123'
    }, {
      'BlockId': '789',
      'LandId': '123'
    }]
  }
];

// assuming lands is like the above example
// and landIDs is an array of strings
var selectLandsWithBlocks = function(lands, landIDs) {
  return _.filter(lands, function(land) {    
    var blocks = land.Blocks;
    var blockHasALandId = function(block) {
      return _.includes(landIDs,block.LandId);
    };
    return _.some(blocks, blockHasALandId);
  });
};

console.log(selectLandsWithBlocks(Lands,[]));
console.log(selectLandsWithBlocks(Lands,['mittens']));
console.log(selectLandsWithBlocks(Lands,['123']));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was a great example and i am working my way through the documents now, what would be the real difference between lodash and ramda.js?

Comment: @Keeano They can be used in similar ways. Lodash is more popular and has more helper functions (like _.camelCase) and can't curry everything (it can somewhat. but not everything). Ramda is a practical functional library, so you can curry and pipe functions very easily. [Here's the same solution with ramda.](https://jsbin.com/wopibiwidi/edit?js,console). There's some boilerplate, but it boils down to list `|> R.filter |> R.any |> R.contains `. Very similar to lodash (since it is the same logic), but Ramda gets easier as you need to extend with more complex transforms.

Comment: i am stuck on an issue involving this and have not found a work around...would you help me if i can provide you with my email? i have read through the docs as you have described and im still getting a weird return... I am using your filter and tweaking it slightly to get something else.

Comment: @Keeano Sure, but no promises. If it's more than a quick fix, I do consulting work.